# Como usar o GitHub no Windows XP?

Tags: git, windows, github

Estou iniciando no mundo do versionamento com GitHub. Tomei esta decisão pois existem duas estações de trabalho que pretendo utilizar para programar. Uma delas é Windows 7 e a outra é Windows XP. O problema é que não consigo instalar o client do GitHub no Windows XP. Andei verificando a respeito, parece que não há mais suporte pro XP pois a versão atual utiliza a interface *metro* que só roda no em Eindows 7 em diante.

Erro que ocorre durante a instalação:

> Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64) failed with the following error message:
>
> > "Installation of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating system. Contact your application vendor."
>
> See the setup log file located at `C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD4C1.tmp\install.log` for more information.

Existe alguma solução para que eu possa sincronizar projetos no GitHub a partir de um Windows XP ou alguma uma aplicação client alternativa para este propósito?

Answer (score 5):

Em vez de usar o cliente do GitHub, pode usar diretamente o git via linha de comando. Baixe e instale do site http://git-scm.com/. Lá mesmo tem um manual bem completo em português sobre como usar: http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/.

Caso prefira uma interface gráfica, existem várias alternativas, aqui uma lista bem longa de possibilidades: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis. Escolha a que lhe agradar mais e que ainda funcione no XP.

---

Considere sériamente fazer o upgrade da maquina que usa o XP, até por questões de segurança.

Comment: O XP é tão mais leve que o Seven >.<